# Enums vs Constant differences on Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

If I need to use const variables I use this approach since it has a type safety.

```
export class LocalStorage {
    static USER_INFO = "user-info";
    static PROFILE_INFO = "profile-info";   
}
```

But it seems we can use `string enums` like so:

```
export enum LocalStorage {
    USER_INFO = "user-info";
    PROFILE_INFO = "profile-info";   
 }
```

What is the difference between these 2 approaches?

Comment: I'd say an enum, since it's more expressive for *why* you need it. A class with static properties isn't self-explanatory. But the right approach can vary, too.

Comment: You can't have a function take in a static field of a class. It can, however, take in any member of an enum.

Comment: @VLAZ Here I just need to maintain a `type safety` for the variables.

Comment: @Sampath OK, so which one is more typesafe: a) an enum `myVar: LocalStorage` or b) a static string `myVar: string`

Comment: **enum** is logical grouping of  your constants . Let's say you want to use different color. Then you make color enum consist of all colors value defined.  Lets say account type which consist value of current, saving, loan, recurring. Its   logical grouping. **Constant** you can define for anything. Now you have to make sure that your enum name has anything to do with logical grouping? Enum name is  LocalStorage but values underneath does not justify as enum

Comment: @vipulpatel Yes, I agree with you. I hope you can put this as an answer too. That will give more visibility.

Comment: As you likely know, asking for "which approach is better" is "bad subjective" on Stack Overflow and therefore off topic. If you can [edit] your question to concentrate on something objectively measurable, you might be able to keep the question from being closed.

Comment: Which one is better is definitely subjective, but how they differ is answerable. Closing this question seems like a bit of a stretch when editing out a couple words would suffice.

Comment: @Sampath I did put as answer. Hope you can vote :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**enum** is logical grouping of your constants. Let's say you want to use different color. Then you make color enum consist of all colors value defined. Lets say **accountType** which consist value of current, saving, loan, recurring. Its logical grouping. **Constant** you can define for anything.

Now you have to make sure that your enum name has anything to do with logical grouping?

In Your case **Enum** name is LocalStorage but values underneath does not justify as enum

Answer (score 17):

I agree with @VLAZ, the best approach can definitely vary. Probably the most significant perk of using an enum is being able to improve type-safety of your functions.

```
export enum LocalStorage {
    USER_INFO = "user-info",
    PROFILE_INFO = "profile-info"
} 

function doSomething(l: LocalStorage) {
}

doSomething("foo"); // error, "foo" is not LocalStorage
doSomething("user-info"); // error, "user-info" is not LocalStorage
doSomething(LocalStorage.USER_INFO); // compiles
```

Overall, enums offer improved type safety (where they make sense), and extending them with new members is generally simpler.

Comment: I like both current answers. This one I think is the better approach 99.528% of the time, but how it's packed is interesting so I also like the @ethane answer.

Comment: The most surprising result here for me is `error, "user-info" is not LocalStorage`

Comment: we don't need types you mean?

Answer (score 8):

While both approaches get the job done for simple scenarios. It's always good practice to use constructs for their intended purposes.

Your class may inadvertently evolve into something more than just holding `static`s. Leading to an amalgamation of concerns. For instance, in the future you may think it necessary to add CRUD functions for local storage, indexedDB, or cookies.

Then you can choose between `const enum`s or `enum`s.

If you need the compiled `enum` at run time, then use a regular TypeScript `enum`.

A `const enum` exists just to help with type-safety. Its usage gets inlined and the `const enum` gets discarded during compilation.